# Insert System date in dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss format

Tags: sql-server, datetime-format

Im trying to insert `Checkout Date` in `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss` format using the following query:

```
insert into Rawtransactions      
(Card Number,Processing Date,CurrencyCode,Checkout Date       
)      

Values      
(      
@NewCardNumber,getdate(),'USD',CONVERT(VARCHAR(24),GETDATE(),113)      
)
```

But It inserted date in this format `02 Sep 2015 14:45:09:390` instead of `02/09/2015 14:45:09:390`. What is the right syntax for this?

**EDITED -** Please note that the `Checkout Date` is an nvarchar field and the Schema cant be changed now. I want to know how can I insert date in this field?

Comment: What is the type of the "Checkout Date" field? (It *should* be Datetime or similar. Don't store date/time values as strings - it won't end well.)

Comment: @JonSkeet Its nvarchar

Comment: Ick. Can you still change it? It's a *really bad idea* to do this...

Comment: @JonSkeet I know Its a bad idea, but im not in the situation to change it

Comment: All of that information should be in the question then.

Comment: Post has been Edited!

Comment: You still haven't said that you can't change the schema (in the question) - the most obvious reaction IMO is "don't do that".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 103) + ' '  + convert(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 14)
```

However it is not recommended to store dates as `varchar()` as it may lead you to some formatting issues like this in future.

Comment: @JonSkeet:- Agreed. There are many disadvantages of storing the dates as `varchar()` including the subtraction or addition of dates and many more. And as far as I have seen varchar is culture specific as well.

Answer (score 0):

Dates are dates.  You can't control the format in which the database stores them; they're just values with a date data type.  If you want to use them later in an application and display them a certain way, then that is up to your application.